# How do I destroy a Java ScriptEngine Instance?

Tags: java, javascript, scriptengine, nashorn

I'm using Java 8.   I'm not a java expert (haven't looked at java since college 10 years ago)

I create an instance of a ScriptEngine (Nashorn if it matters).
I use it to eval several javascript files.

The script chugs along quite happily in its own little javascript world.  I love it.

I also have a File System WatchService running, in case some of my java scripts get modified.
When they get modified, I create a new ScriptEngine, and eval the new versions of the javascript files using the new ScriptEngine object.

My problem is, I cant "kill" the old scriptEngine once I create the new one.  The old script keeps on running indefinitely.

I really want to free up the resources being used by the old scriptEngine object. AND I want it to stop doing the stuff its doing (since it could conflict with the new instance if they both try doing the same things).

So ... How do I completely eliminate the old ScriptEngine, including any threads spawned inside of it?

Comment: Consider using [the concurrency utilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) instead of raw threads.

Comment: Did you ever find a way? Seems like a hole in the script engine API to me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I completely abandoned the project based on this critical flaw.

Comment: @BrentLarsen: Wow. Ouch. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the old problem with the leaking threads. Have you got a handle of the thread? Does something inherits Thread? Ok, then something like this:

```
private void stopThread(Thread thread) {
    final Thread moribund = thread;
    if (moribund != null) {
        thread = null;
        moribund.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Maybe it helps.

Comment: the threads are created in the javascript file using something like this...  (new Thread(function() {...})).start();  I could potentially make a big array of all of the spawned threads if that would help.

Comment: I'd really prefer to kill them on the java side of my app (instead of inside of the JS part of the app) since I have control of the Java side.  I was really hoping for a way to just pull the plug on the script engine so it would free up everything associated with it.  I dont want to have to "trust" the builders of the scripts to clean up after themselves in order for my app to be solid.

Comment: Can you add the Threads to a ThreadGroup? It's done within the Thread constructor. Then you might kill all the threads at once.

Comment: The purpose behind using a scripting engine was to allow other people to do "whatever they want" inside the scripts, without breaking the java app.  And I don't have control over what they decide to do inside of there.   I could (potentially) create a nice little ThreadSpawner class and require them to use that or not get any help if their stuff breaks.  But really its about more than just threads,  when a ScriptEngine expires, I want everything associated with it to be cleaned up, and all of the memory and other resources to become available to other things.

Comment: Well, I took some investigations, but without great success. Last approach may be to take JavaScripts "clearInterval" (if this is possible with Nashorn). But then again there should be a signal. Sorry, I guess I'm out here. Good luck.

Comment: Even without threads there seems to be no way to destroy an Engine. If a user runs `while true { print "LOL" }` there seems to be no way to destroy the engine and stop this executing?